# After instruction still can not make for loop with C#

Tags: c#

I started a C# course now and there is an assignment where I have to create a "palindrome detector" program. Point is that user inputs some word or sentence, then I have to remove chars like `,.;:!?` and space from it. I have done that with two different methods, because char method can not remove space so I wrote another method for it.

After "cleaning" operation program reversing input what user gave, and comparing original user input and reversed user input to each other. It they are same it prints "It is palindrome", if they are different it prints "It is not palindrome". That is working fine, BUT THE PROBLEM IS I have to put them in for loop. It have to ask input again and again, until user give empty.

This would be very easy, but somehow I can not do it.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Palindromi
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hei! Tervetuloa palindromin tunnistusohjelmaan. Tämä tunnistaa, onko syöttämäsi sana sama toisinpäin!");
            Console.Write("Anna teksti (tyhjä lopettaa): ");
            string userinput = Console.ReadLine(); //userinput is user's input, this is what you have to modify. remove some chars and reverse it.

            if (userinput == "")
            {
                Console.ReadLine();//when i have loop this have to be "break". This meant to break for loop when i have it.
            }

            char[] removechars = { '.', ':', ';', ',', '!', '?' };//this is the list of "have to be removed" chars

            string userinput_without_chars = userinput.Trim(removechars); //this method remove chars which are listed
            string userinput_without_chars_space = userinput_without_chars.Replace( " ", ""); //replace space with empty


            string reverse_string, reversed;

            reverse_string = userinput_without_chars_space;
            reversed = "";

            int len;
            len = userinput_without_chars_space.Length - 1;

            while (len >= 0)
            {
                reversed = reversed + reverse_string[len];
                len--;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Sana käännettynä on {0}", reversed); //tells user input reversed

            if (userinput_without_chars_space == reversed)//check is the userinput same than reversed user input
            {
                Console.Write("On palindromi.");//it is palindrome
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write("Ei ole palindromi.");//it is not palindrome
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put all of your main into a method, then exit/return from the method when the user enters an empty string

Comment: `Trim` only removes characters from the beginning and end of a string.  It does not remove characters from the middle.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a question in this question. What is your question?

Comment: From your question it sounds like you have it working, but (1) you are required to use a for loop, and (2) you aren't sure how? Are you trying to write something that takes in a string, writes if it is a palindrome, than asks for input again, until the user enters nothing? Are you checking if the sentence is a palindrome, or words in the sentence? We need a summary of what you're asking.

Comment: I just have to make for loop it. Program must ask word again and again, until user enters nothing. Just enter nothing and press enter it stop the whole program. thanks for the info juharr. I have to do that completely thing with replace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially do something along these lines:

```
var running = true;

while(running)
{
     var input = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
     var phrase = input.Sanitize(new List<string>() {".", ",", "?", "!", "'", "&", "%", "$", " "});

     if(phrase.IsPalindrome())
         Console.Writeline("Input was palindrome.");
}

public static string Sanitize(this string input, IList<string> punctuation) =>
     String.Join(String.Empty, input.Where(character => punctuation.Contains(character) == false));

public static bool IsPalindrome(this string sentence)
{
    for (int l = 0, r = sentence.Length - 1; l < r; l++, r--)
        if (sentence[l] != sentence[r])
            return false;

    return true;
}

public static void Close(string input) 
{
    // Some logic to see if the application should stop.  
}
```

You could create another method that looks for commands, or keystrokes, then sets the boolean to run as false.  Which would break the infinite loop.  You could also do an abrupt close with `Environment.Exit`.

Answer (score 1):

The very simplest approach is replace your `Console.ReadLine()` where you want to break to `return`.

Alternatively, you could wrap the logic in another while loop.

```
while (userinput != "")
{
    // Remove chars
    // rest of your logic

    /* IMPORTANT */
    userinput = Console.Readline();
}
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() is only temporarily thing, biggest problem is to put this program to loop. I'll try Peter Smith advice, it i can not get it work i'll be back as Arnold said :D

Comment: it works now, it was too easy :D Also repaired trim with replace method.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the symbols from the input, you can use the `Regex.Replace` method. In this case, you can be sure, that the specified symbols will be correctly removed from the input string. Note, that you can handle the whitespaces along with other characters you mentioned, like in the code snippet below:

```cs
var CharactersToRemove { get; set; } = " ,.;:!?";
var processedInput = Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), $"[{CharactersToRemove}]", string.Empty);
```

Note, that here I used `input.ToLower()` to convert the input to a lowercase string. This will make the palindrome tests case-insensitive. Should you need case-sensitive palindrome tests, just remove the `.ToLower()` part.

There is no need to reverse the input string to check if it is a palindrome. You can check this within one `for` loop as follows:

```cs
bool CheckForBeingaAPalindrome(string input)
{
    var frontIndex = 0;
    var tailIndex = input.Length - 1;

    for (; frontIndex < tailIndex;)
    {
        if (input[frontIndex] != input[tailIndex])
            return false;

        ++frontIndex;
        --tailIndex;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note, that in this case you only iterate over the elements of the input string once. This approach will give you al least 4 times better performance than the one you used.

Below, you can find a complete minimal working solution to your problem.

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using static System.Console;

namespace Assignment
{
    public static class PalindromeFinder
    {
        public static string CharactersToRemove { get; set; } = " ,.;:!?";

        public static bool IsPalindrome(string input)
        {
            var processedInput = RemoveUnnecessaryCharacters(input);
            return CheckForBeingAPalindrome(processedInput);
        }

        private static string RemoveUnnecessaryCharacters(string input)
        {
            return Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), $"[{CharactersToRemove}]", string.Empty);
        }

        private static bool CheckForBeingAPalindrome(string input)
        {
            var frontIndex = 0;
            var tailIndex = input.Length - 1;

            for (; frontIndex < tailIndex;)
            {
                if (input[frontIndex] != input[tailIndex])
                    return false;

                ++frontIndex;
                --tailIndex;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ContinuouslyCheckUserInputForBeingAPalindrome();
        }

        private static void ContinuouslyCheckUserInputForBeingAPalindrome()
        {
            while (FetchUserInputFromConsole() is string input
                   && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            {
                var isPalindrome = PalindromeFinder.IsPalindrome(input);
                var modifier = isPalindrome ? "a" : "not a";
                WriteLine($"It is {modifier} palindrome");
            }
        }

        private static string FetchUserInputFromConsole()
        {
            Write("Enter a string: ");
            return ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```